# Default Sales Order/Quote menu disappers after publishing customization

Tags: acumatica

We are in to acumatica 20 r2 and when we publish the custom package, the default report menu print salesorder/quote  option disappears.

We have custom reports which are added by overriding the initialize method of salesorderentry graph in my extension.

```
public override void Initialize()
{
        base.Initialize();
        base.Base.report.AddMenuAction(embroideryreport);
        base.Base.report.AddMenuAction(embroiderysoreport);
        base.Base.report.AddMenuAction(screenprintreport);
        base.Base.report.AddMenuAction(screenprintsoreport);
}
```

I am not able to figure out the reason for missing report. I have upgraded the workflow to latest version and still having the issue.

**UPDATE**

I did not call base.Initialize() initially and since the default report is not coming, I thought it may be due to not invoking the base method.

I have tried bahaa-zantout suggestion and the base report is already tagged to the report menu and when I commented on the code in Initialize method for adding the report the default report appeared again under-report menu.

It looks like there is conflict in the workflow and I am not able to figure it out.

I have tried to add those report in the workflow action section and tagged them to Report and the entire report menu disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it is due to this statement or not but when I changed the following statement it fixed the issue

```
[PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.ReportsFolder)]
```

to

```
[PXButton]
```

for Report action

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> embroideryreport;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Embroidery Production Report", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    //[PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.ReportsFolder)]
    [PXButton]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you initialization method to....

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    base.Base.report.AddMenuAction(embroideryreport);
    base.Base.report.AddMenuAction(embroiderysoreport);
    base.Base.report.AddMenuAction(screenprintreport);
    base.Base.report.AddMenuAction(screenprintsoreport);
}
```

From Acumatica DEV documentation portal

You do not need to explicitly invoke the Initialize() method on the previous extension levels; these methods are called automatically. Invoking base.Initialize() makes no sense, because the base variable points to the base class, which is PXGraphExtension (not the base graph). The PXGraphExtension class defines Initialize() as an empty method.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt the following in attempt to restore the toolbar menu item.

1. Navigate to the Sales Order screen in the customization project
2. Go to the Actions
3. Locate the missing print options (ie. printSalesOrder) and place the Toolbar folder in the original folder in this case "Reports". If it doesn't work try moving to "Actions" and see if it appears.

[See example screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTEeh.png)